# Abel's test for improper integrals with only integrable functions

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, examples-counterexamples

I know this following formulation of Abel's test for improper integrals:

> Let $f,g:[a,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions, where
>
> - $\int_a^\infty f(t)dt$ converges.
> - $g$ is monotone decreasing, bounded and continuously differentiable. 
>   Then $\int_a^\infty f(t)g(t)dt$ converges.

The proof I know uses integration by parts, so I am not sure if one can strengthen it, but I'm looking for counter-examples of stronger versions. More specifically, when $f$ is only Riemann integrable on any compact interval, but I currently can't think of any.

Comment: Are you using that $g\geq 0$? Otherwise this is false as seen with $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $g(x)=-x$ on $[1,\infty]$

Comment: It can definitely weakened, but it will require some measure theory

Comment: How about $f(x)=1,\ g(x)=\frac1x,\ a=1$?  $f$ is integrable on any compact interval, $g$ is decreasing and continuously, differentiable, $\int_a^\infty fg$ diverges.

Comment: I suspect that you are missing some conditions on $g$, such as the boundedness.

Comment: I did omit the boundedness condition. I was searching for a way where the continuity condition is essential, but going by the answers given below it seems that I can not find such a counter-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that OP mistakingly forgot to include the boundedness of $g$. Then the proof using integration by parts carries over to a more general case with due modification:

> Let $f, g : [a, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions such that the following holds:
>
> - $f$ is locally integrable and $\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ converges.
> - $g$ is bounded and non-decreasing.
>
> Then $\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ converges.

For the proof, let $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$. Then

$$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= F(b)g(b) - \int_{a}^{b} F(x) \, \mathrm{d}g(x), $$

where the integral in the right-hand side is regarded as a [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral). Indeed, this holds when $f$ is continuous and then extends to a general case by approximating $f$ by continuous functions in $L^1$-norm on $[a, b]$. Then by the assumption, we note the following:

- Since $g(b)$ converges as $b\to\infty$ by the assumption, the term $F(b)g(b)$ also converges as $b\to\infty$.
- Since $F$ is bounded, we may choose a bound $M$ of $f$. Then for any $ a \leq b \leq c$,
  $$ \left| \int_{a}^{c} F(x) \, \mathrm{d}g(x) - \int_{a}^{b} F(x) \, \mathrm{d}g(x) \right|
  \leq M|g(c) - g(b)|. $$
  This shows that the net $\{ \int_{a}^{b} F(x) \, \mathrm{d}g(x) \}_{b \in [a,\infty)}$ is Cauchy and hence converges.

This completes the proof.

Comment: Can I ask, f(x) is not continuous, so how does this integration by parts formula hold?

Comment: @alan23273850, Here is another approach: Assume WLOG that $g$ is right-continuous, and let $\mathrm{d}g$ be the [Lebesgue–Stieltjes measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration) associated to $g$. Then \begin{align*}\int_{(a,b]}f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x&=\int_{(a,b]}f(x)\left(g(b)-\int_{(x,b]}\mathrm{d}g(y)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=F(b)g(b)-\int_{(a,b]}\int_{(a,y]}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}g(y)\\&=F(b)g(b)-\int_{(a,b]}F(y)\,\mathrm{d}g(y),\end{align*} where the second step follows from the Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Weak sufficient conditions are that $\int_a^\infty f(x) \, dx$ converges and $g$ is bounded and monotone (decreasing or increasing).  By the [second mean value theorem for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Second_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals), there exists $\xi \in [c_1,c_2]$ such that

$$\int_{c_1}^{c_2} f(x) g(x) \, dx = g(c_1) \int_{c_1}^\xi f(x) \, dx + g(c_2)\int_\xi^{c_2} f(x) \, dx,$$

Since $g$ is bounded with $|g(x)| \leqslant M$, we have

$$\left|\int_{c_1}^{c_2} f(x) g(x) \, dx\right|\leqslant |g(c_1)| \left|\int_{c_1}^\xi f(x) \, dx\right| + |g(c_2)|\left|\int_\xi^{c_2} f(x) \, dx\right|\\ \leqslant M \left|\int_{c_1}^\xi f(x) \, dx\right| + M\left|\int_\xi^{c_2} f(x) \, dx\right|$$

For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $C > a$ such that for all $c_2 \geqslant \xi \geqslant  c_1 > C$,

$$ \left|\int_{c_1}^\xi f(x) \, dx\right|, \,\,\left|\int_\xi^{c_2} f(x) \, dx\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2M},$$

which implies

$$\left|\int_{c_1}^{c_2} f(x) g(x) \, dx\right| < \epsilon$$

Thus, $\int_a^\infty f(x) g(x) \, dx$ converges by the Cauchy criterion.

---

A counterexample where $\int_a^\infty f(x) \, dx$ fails to converge --  while other conditions are met -- has been given in comments.

Also, the convergence of $\int_a^\infty f(x) \, dx$ is not a necessary condition. An example is $a=1$, $f(x) = g(x) = 1/x$, where

$$\int_1^\infty f(x) \, dx = \infty, \,\,\int_1^\infty f(x)g(x) \, dx = 1$$